# Messenger Extensions Js SDK Error 2071011

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

when i run my chatbot, it's worked on mobile but not in desktop.
It shows me a 2071011 error code on the console from function getContext() when i'm trying to get psid. I've checked whitelist domain and messenger_extensions = true in my code but it doesn't work for the desktop version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean the Desktop Mac OS app or Messenger on Desktop Chrome/Firefox/Safari?